# R: Filling enclosed areas in contour

Tags: r, plot, contour

Im drawing a knn-classification plot in R using plot to plot the samples and contour to plot the lines that classify the plane.

Here is my code:

```
k<-1
datax<-rbind(matrix(rnorm(30,-1,5.25),15,2),matrix(rnorm(36,1,5.25),18,2))
datay<-rbind(matrix(1,15,1),matrix(0,18,1))
plot(datax[,1], datax[,2],pch = datay+1,axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
box()
n <- 1000
xp <- seq(length=n, from = min(datax[,1]), to = max(datax[,1]))
yp <- seq(length=n,from = min(datax[,2]) ,to = max(datax[,2]))
gr <- expand.grid(xp, yp)
library(class)
z <- as.numeric(knn(datax, gr, datay,k))-1
zM <- matrix(z, n, n, byrow = FALSE)
contour(xp, yp, zM, xlab="x",ylab="",nlevels = 1 ,lwd=2, add=TRUE, drawlabels =FALSE)
```

My question is: How can i color the enclosed areas in the plot? I tried filled.contour but there is no add parameter. I simply want the area where the classifier is = 0 white and where it classifies = 1 in blue. How should i do this?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `contour`, you can use `contourLines` to keep the coordinates of the edges of the contour lines and plot them with `polygon`.

```
plot(datax[,1], datax[,2],axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE, type="n")
box()
cL <- contourLines(xp, yp, zM,nlevels = 1)
lapply(cL,function(x)polygon(x$x,x$y,col="red"))
points(datax[,1], datax[,2],pch = datay+1)
```

However it is not perfect with contour lines that reach the edges of the plot (see the left lower corner of the second plot), so it will need some hand-made tuning:
[image]

**Edit**: In the case of nested contour lines, I don't think there is an easy way to deal with it but here is one way:

```
library(splancs)
ord <- sapply(lapply(cL,function(x)datay[inout(datax,cbind(x$x,x$y))]),
              median) #Check what values are present in the polygon and 
                      #take the most common one
plot(datax[,1], datax[,2],axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE, type="n")
box()
lapply(cL[ord==1],function(x)polygon(x$x,x$y,col="blue"))
lapply(cL[ord==0],function(x)polygon(x$x,x$y,col="white"))
points(datax[,1], datax[,2],pch = datay+1)
```

[image]

**2nd Edit:** There is of course also the possibility of using function `image` in your case:

```
image(xp, yp, zM, col=c("transparent","blue"))
points(datax[,1], datax[,2],pch = datay+1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I do this the little circles and traingles are gone in the plot. How do I keep them?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a line: `points(datax[,1], datax[,2],pch = datay+1)`. You have to plot them after the polygon filling, otherwise they would be overwritten by it.

Comment: Thank you! However there is a problem: for example if you set.seed(24) and plot it the above way there are areas plotted in blue eventhough they don't belong to the respective class. Don't I somehow have to pass the Information of knn to the plot so it knows which regions to color and which not?

Comment: Alright but now the same problem occurs when I do set.seed(10). I mean I have set up the grid-matrix zM that already contains all the level information, is there no way of simply saying if the value is equal to on the make a blue background if it is zero then make it white?

Comment: Yes there is, by using function image (see 2nd edit). I didn't propose it earlier because i hadn t check what you had in zM (and since i don t know function knn i couldn t guess), but since you already did all that work, that s obviously the easiest way to go here. Sorry for not seing that earlier.